# TextViews don't show up in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

In my Android app, I try to add a TextView to add titles to some of my Activities. However, it doesn't seem to work, since in none of my activities the TextViews don't show up. I'm new to developing Android apps, so I may be doing something fundamentally wrong, but I tried out to add different elements (Buttons, Plain Text, ...) and they all show up, I only have the Problem with my Textview.

Here's my code:

````
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WishlistActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="173dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="625dp"
        android:text="Wishlist stuff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

Comment: needs more detail, are you setting the correct file in your activity/fragment ? can you see it in the design editor ? what color of text are you using, are you sure the text and background aren't the same ?

Comment: most likely it's because you have MASSIVE margins, `android:layout_marginBottom="625dp"` is way too big, this isn't the proper way of using constraint layout if you're going to use constraints to all 4 positions and then just moving it with margins, that's pointless. rather just use a top constraint OR bottom constraint and then for left and/or right. you will _most likely_ never need a margin higher than 32 or 64

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks a lot! This worked for me, didn't quite understand how to position items other than margins. Works now!

Comment: no problem, i'm glad to see you're starting off with constraint layout, linear/relative definitely isn't the way to go, but older tutorials still teach it to people, which is just a waste of time. constraint layout does take some practice, keep at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="173dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="156dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="625dp"
        android:text="Wishlist stuff"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFwVD.png)

**There is no error in code just correct the margin according to your screen size.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove margins inside Textview and try it

Comment: Thanks, adjusting the margins worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just drag&dropped the textview into the ContraintLayout and moved it to a specific place. Android Studio moves the View by adjusting the margins accordingly.
And then you set it to 0dp, hoping it would expand, which it normally would do. You just missed to remove or adjust the margins afterwards.

Try this:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Wishlist stuff"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```